# Winforms designer debugging is not for Netcore app

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, windows-forms-designer

I trying to designer debugging for my winforms netcore application using devenv.exe, but breakpoint is never hit the source. is designer debugging working in VS2019 .

VS: VS2019
Framework: NetCore 3.1

Is anything i have missed?

Comment: might be trivial, but check that you are in Debug, not Release.

Comment: And, have you tried putting a breakpoint on something that is easy to recognize (like the `Main` function)?

Comment: Im using in debug mode only

Comment: @Flydog57 yes i have placed in constructor.

Comment: Design support for .NETCore is quite complicated, the designer must run out-of-process since VS uses .NETFramework.  As a side-effect you cannot expect the usual debug support, wrong process.